# How should I customize a fail2ban filter for a usage in conjunction of a sshd that runs in a container and logs with systemd?

Tags: systemd, fail2ban

I'm running an SSH daemon in a container with Docker. As the latter is managed by `systemd` and the sshd logs to `stdout`, the relevant data to detect attackers appears in `systemd`'s journal, but its entries have an extra prefix like this:

`Feb 13 21:51:25 my.example.com dockerd[427]: Feb 13 18:51:25 sshd[555]: Invalid user ts3bot from 180.166.17.122 port 43474`

The jail is configured with this snippet:

```
[sshd]

enabled = true
mode    = aggressive
filter  = sshd[mode=%(mode)s]
port    = ssh
```

It seems that this line from `filters.d/sshd.conf` contains what I want to change:

```
journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
```

But I can't find any helpful documentation on `journalmatch`'s configuration. I'm using `fail2ban` 0.10.

Can someone explain how the part on the right of the equal sign is to be interpreted ?

When I hopefully will figure out how to adjust that value, should I edit the `filters.d/sshd.conf` directly (it's provided from an Arch package) or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the option having an extra sshd jail for the host system itself, here's what I would do:

1. **Version** – Use fail2ban version >= 0.9 that supports use of `systemd` as backend. (BTW: Version 0.11 is pretty new and might not be stable yet, but I like the new feature to automatically increase ban times for each new match from the same IP.)
2. **Jail** –  Create a separate jail `jail.d/sshd-docker`. Adopt settings from original sshd jail as needed. Maybe start low ban times for safety first and increase later. Add `backend = systemd` to that new `sshd-docker` jail. Could look like this:

   ```
   [sshd-docker]
   enabled  = true
   filter   = sshd-docker
   action   = iptables
   backend  = systemd
   maxretry = 5
   findtime = 1d
   bantime  = 2w
   ```
3. **Filter** – I prefer to leave filter files and original jail.conf file untouched so I can easily upgrade to newer fail2ban versions. Therefore I would suggest to duplicate the filter file `filter.d/sshd.conf` to `filter.d/sshd-docker.conf` and refer to that new filter in your `sshd-docker` jail (as seen above).
4. **Filter/regex** – Adopt regex in `filter.d/sshd-docker.conf` to match your log entries. Could be as simple as changing this

   ```
   _daemon = sshd
   ```

   to

   ```
   _daemon = docker
   ```

   as the `_daemon` directive is used to construct the __prefix_line regex as you can see in `filter.d/common.conf`.
5. **Filter/journalmatch** – As far as I can see from fail2ban-regex man page the `journalmatch` directive overrides other filters. Therefore you might also need to change this line in your `filter.d/sshd-docker.conf`

   ```
   journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
   ```

   to

   ```
   journalmatch =
   ```

   (In fail2ban 0.11 you could also just remove this line. Not sure when prior versions stopped to require a `journalmatch =` entry in a filter file.)
6. **Test** – Reload fail2ban and check how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I configm that creating a new filter with jourmalmatch = and _daemon = docker/container_name (that's how i'm logging in syslog) fixed the issue for me.

in theory a new filter should not be needed, as everything in the filter can be overwritten in the jail according to the man page jail.conf. however, for me it did not work. _daemon overwrite was not taken into account in jail.local.

the only way to have it working for me was to copy sshd.conf into docker_sshd.conf and update _daemon and journalmatch fields.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).